# pygame.transform.rotate not working

Tags: python, pygame

The code below is a draw function of an npc class in a game I'm making in pygame (source: https://github.com/hailfire006/games/blob/master/strategy%20gamev2), and it all works great except for this one line

```
pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image,angle)
```

which should rotate the npc towards the point it's moving to.  For whatever reason, it's just not rotating.  I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm not storing the result of this function into a variable but I'm not sure.

the rest of the function:

```
    target = get_target(self)
    if target != 0:
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.x - target[0], self.y - target[1])) + 90
        self.sprite.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image,angle)
        self.shoot(target)
    if self.moving != False:
        if abs(self.x - self.moving[0]) < 3 and abs(self.y - self.moving[1]) < 3:
            self.moving = False
        else:
            self.move(self.moving)
            if target == 0:
                angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.x - self.moving[0], self.y - self.moving[1])) + 90
                pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image,angle)
    if self.hp <= 0:
        objects.remove(self)
        return

    self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect()
    self.sprite.rect.topleft = [self.x - 20, self.y - 20]
    window.blit(self.sprite.image, self.sprite.rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `self._base_sprite` and a `self._active_sprite`

Set your `init` code to initialise `_base_sprite` and then change your line from:

```
pygame.transform.rotate(self.sprite.image,angle)
```

to:

```
self._active_sprite = pygame.transform.rotate(self._base_sprite.image,angle)
```

and then blit your active sprite

The reasoning is:

- When rotating a sprite you buffer out the image so you don't lose pixels (including any alpha'd corners), which gains space
- If you rotate a rotated sprite you repeat this process
- If you keep rotating you will run out of memory
- Thus, we retain two surfaces in memory, one "base" one and one "active" one.

Additionally, your .rect adjustment code should probably be only done in your `init` function. You're trying to adjust the center of the sprite, I assume?

Edit: Note, [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261163/out-of-memory-when-using-pygame-transform-rotate?rq=1) is highly related (and in the sidebar).